# Google Visualization Annotated Time Line select dot size

Tags: google-visualization

Is there any way to change the "select dot" size on a Google Visualization API Annotated Time Line?

I have found that I can set the line size with the thickness property, but can't find anything for the select dot size.

```
chart.draw(data, {
                        displayAnnotations: true, 
                        displayRangeSelector:false,
                        fill:30,
                        thickness:3,
                        colors:['#59761d', '#1d4376', '#761d1d']
                    });
```

I have read [the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html#Configuration_Options), but don't see anything on it.  I had assumed Google themselves used this component in Google Analytics, and Google Analytics definitely has larger select dots.  Perhaps they simply borrowed some code for that, and they are indeed different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use Configuration Option Names from other visualizations(for example the option for dot size in a line graph is called "pointSize"), but I doubt they will work.

In my experience, the documentation for the visualizations are very thorough, and if you cannot find it there, it probably does not exist yet. Sorry!